# Cropping UI images

Tags: ios, image, swift3

I have a SceneKit view that fills my screen. My goal is to let the user take snapshots of that scene, but the snapshots are not the whole screen, but an inset portion in a UIImageView which is slightly smaller than the screen. Ideally, the user should not notice, the image on top should be identical to the scene behind it.

I have coded this up using `snapshot` and `cropped`, but as you can see in the image, the scale ends up way off - see the width of the yellow line, and the size of the windows? It's also not positioned correctly, it's somewhat down and to the left from where it should be - the upper left should be below the line of windows, but you can see it is at the roofline above them. I can't see the original snapshot because the debugger QuickLook refuses to show it.

[image]

There's not much code to it, anyone see the problem:

```
    let background = sceneView.snapshot().cgImage!
    let cropped = background.cropping(to: overlayView.frame)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(overlayView.frame.size, false, 1.0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.setAlpha(0.50)
    context!.draw(cropped!, in: overlayView.bounds)
    let transparent = context!.makeImage();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    overlayView.image = UIImage.init(cgImage: transparent!, scale: 1.0, orientation: .downMirrored)
```

I have tried various scales and rects to no avail. I assume this is something very easy.

**UPDATE:** after several tries I was able to get quicklook to work. The snapshot is indeed the entire background as I would expect. But it is much larger than I would expect too - its 640, 998 while the cropped version is 228, 304. That explains the "zooming". This leads me to believe that the frame size of the inset view is *NOT a direct relationship to the image size*. Does that ring any bells? Is there some other rect I should be using rather than overlayView.frame?

Comment: Have you tried setting the view's contentMode?  Also, you may want to try and set jitteringEnabled = true.  Then turn it off after the snapshot.  The snapshot image will be better quality, but the downside is that there is a performance penalty.

Comment: Can you be more specific on contentMode? That sounds like something I should try. Also see the update.

Comment: Well I was able to get the results to be MUCH closer simply by multiplying the bounds by 2. Any idea why?

Comment: You can try setting overlayView's UIViewContentMode  to scaleToFill, scaleAspectFit, scaleAspectFill...and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I assume the problem is that the frame coordinates are in one set of units and the image coordinates are in another. I was able to solve the problem this way:

```
    let croprect = CGRect(x: overlayView.frame.origin.x * 2, y: overlayView.frame.origin.y * 2 - 45, width: overlayView.frame.width * 2, height: overlayView.frame.height * 2)
    let drawrect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: overlayView.frame.width * 2, height: overlayView.frame.height * 2)
    let background = sceneView.snapshot()
    let cropped = background.cgImage!.cropping(to: croprect)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(drawrect.size, false, 0.0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.setAlpha(0.50)
    context!.draw(cropped!, in: drawrect)
    let transparent = context!.makeImage();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

I'm *extremely* curious why I had to adjust the Y starting point to get them to line up, anyone have an idea?

Comment: Calling BeginImageContext with a third parameter of `0` is a huge improvement. I can't imagine what you thought you were doing setting the scale arbitrarily to `1` in your original code...

Comment: Example code. But it had no visual effect at 1 or 0, I tried both options in both places.